# MySQL entries sorted by date in wrong order

Tags: php, mysql, date, sql-order-by

Using a MySQL `SELECT` query via PHP, I would like to order my entries by date. The query I'm using is:

```
$query = "SELECT title, file, oblong_pic, square_pic,
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%W %d %M %Y') AS date
FROM dyhamb ORDER BY date DESC";
```

I have four entries dated: 24/7/2012, 1/7/2012, 5/6/2012 and 10/4/2012 and would like them to be displayed in that order however they are being displayed as: 24/7/2012, 10/4/2010, 5/6/2012 and 1/7/2012.

I can only think that I've set my query up incorrectly somehow but I don't see where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Weekday name, i.e. Monday, Sunday. Am I right in thinking it's ordering by weekday name, rather than by year-month-day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%W in DATE_FORMAT is weekday name, so sort starts with that

If you want to use date alias you should rewrite your sql query to:

```
$query = "SELECT title, file, oblong_pic, square_pic, date AS sort_date,
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%W %d %M %Y') AS date
FROM dyhamb ORDER BY sort_date DESC";
```

Comment: It appears that unless it's in y-m-d format order by will not work as expected.

Comment: If `date` field is defined as either of MySQL date types: `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE` ordering will work as expected. I assumed field is defined properly because `DATE_FORMAT` function would return invalid value if trying ti pass something other than date/time type or properly formatted string. In short, it will work if `date` field contains values like `"2018-04-05"` but will not work if type of `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` with values like `"Apr-05-2018"` obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a column alias with the same name with an existing column. Thus the ordering occurs based on the DATE_FORMAT function, instead of the date real value.

As a good practice, I suggest to remove the DATE_FORMAT function from the mysql query and leave this part to your php script.

Answer (score 0):

`DATE_FORMAT` returns string, therefore you are ordering it as string, in which you are using `%W`, so you are ordering firstly by weekday name. If you want to order by date then just do this:

```
SELECT title, file, oblong_pic, square_pic, date
FROM dyhamb 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

If you really want to select formated date then add `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%W %d %M %Y') as formatted_date` to selected columns, note that column alias is not `date` but `formatted_date`.